# I can't view my selected data from MySQL using INNER JOIN statements

Tags: java, mysql, sql

```
public ArrayList getDuty(){
    ArrayList<Sched> schedList = new ArrayList<Sched>();
    DBController db = new DBController();
    String dbQuery = "Select d.dutyName, v.venueAddress, s.scheduleId, s.scheduleDate, s.scheduleTime FROM schedule s INNER JOIN dutyvolunteers dv ON s.dutyVolunteersId = dv.dutyVolunteersId INNER JOIN duty d ON dv.dutyId = d.dutyId INNER JOIN venue v ON d.venueId = v.venueId";

    try{
        db.getConnection();
        ResultSet rs = db.readRequest(dbQuery);
        while(rs.next())
        {
            Sched b = new Sched(rs.getString("vName"),rs.getString("vNRIC"),rs.getString("dutyName"),rs.getString("venueAddress"), rs.getString("scheduleDate"), rs.getString("scheduleTime"));
            schedList.add(b);
        }
     }

    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    db.terminate();
    return schedList;
}
```

My retrieve codes are above. Well, it actually says that it was successfully connected to my database. However, it does not print out all my selected data. And it also says that my connection is closed.

My DB CONTROLLER codes

```
public class DBController {
    private Connection con; 

    public void testDriver() throws Exception { 
        System.out.println("Initializing Server... "); 
    try { 
        Class.forName("org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver"); 
        System.out.println(" Driver Found."); 
    } 
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) { 
        System.out.println(" Driver Not Found, exiting.."); 
        throw (e); 
        } 
    } 
    public void getConnection(){ 
        String url = ""; 
        try { 
            url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/sea_games"; 
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "IT1639User", "user"); 
            System.out.println("Successfully connected to " + url+ "."); 
        } 
        catch (java.sql.SQLException e) { 
            System.out.println("Connection failed ->"+ url); 
            System.out.println(e); 
        } 
    } 

    public ResultSet readRequest(String dbQuery) {
        ResultSet rs = null;
        System.out.println("DB Query: " + dbQuery);
        try {
            // create a statement object
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            // execute an SQL query and get the result
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(dbQuery);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return rs;
    }

    public int updateRequest(String dbQuery) {
        int count = 0;
        System.out.println("DB Query: " + dbQuery);
        try {
            // create a statement object
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            // execute an SQL query and get the result
            count = stmt.executeUpdate(dbQuery);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return count;
    }

    public void terminate() {
        // close connection
        try {
            con.close();
            System.out.println("Connection is closed");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] arg)throws Exception{
        DBController db = new DBController();
        db.testDriver();
    }
    public boolean executeUpdate(String dbQuery) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for readRequest and getConnection methods please?

Comment: Can you show the code of `DBController`?

Comment: If your connection is closed, your query wont work

Comment: my DBController codes are posted @Jens

Comment: @zelo I think the problem is the `rs.getString(...). Try to change Select d.dutyName` to `Select d.dutyName as dutyName` and so on.

Comment: i changed the rs.getString(...) values already..but it still won't print out my data @Jens

Comment: @zelo you should add `as Name` in the select.

Comment: Where are you expecting to see your data? I've only looked briefly, but cannot see any print statements that would print out your results. Are you getting any exceptions at all, or just not seeing any data? Try printing out how many rows you are getting back. When you run the exact same SQL query directly in the database, do you get the same number of rows?